# node-redis throws Socket closed unexpectedly on any action and doesn't reconnect

Tags: typescript, redis, node-redis

I have redis-command 6+ version and using node-redis 4.5.1 .
I want to connect to my local redis database and retrieve any key just to see if it works.
For example command HGETALL Caas.ExposeServerCache:IE:DB:G001 in redis cli works fine and shows me my keys. But when i run my code below:

```
 let client = createClient({
            url: 'redis://localhost:8081'
        });
        client.on("error", (err) => console.error("client err====:", err));
        client.on('connect', () => console.log('client is connect'));
        client.on('reconnecting', () => console.log('client is reconnecting'));
        client.on('ready', () => console.log('client is ready'));
        await client.connect();
        let kek = await client.hGetAll('Caas.ExposeServerCache:IE:DB:G001');
        console.log("KEK::: " + kek);
```

It shows me an error that  Socket closed unexpectedly and drops my app instead of reconnecting. Here is error log:

```
client is connect
client is ready
client err====: SocketClosedUnexpectedlyError: Socket closed unexpectedly
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\WORK\RWE_API_UI_Tests\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\socket.js:181:118)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:646:26)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)
client is reconnecting
  1) [API Tests] › APITests\RabbitMQTest.spec.ts:29:5 › RabbitMQ API Test › Redis connection test ==

    Error: Socket closed unexpectedly

       at ..\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\socket.js:181

      179 |                 .once('close', hadError => {
      180 |                 if (!hadError && __classPrivateFieldGet(this, _RedisSocket_isOpen, "f") && __classPrivateFieldGet(this, _RedisSocket_socket, "f") === socket) {
    > 181 |                     __classPrivateFieldGet(this, _RedisSocket_instances, "m", _RedisSocket_onSocketError).call(this, new errors_1.SocketClosedUnexpectedlyError());
          |                                                                                                                      ^
      182 |                 }
      183 |             })
      184 |                 .on('drain', () => {

        at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\WORK\RWE_API_UI_Tests\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\socket.js:181:118)
        at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:646:26)
        at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
        at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:687:12)

client is connect
client is ready
```

Despite saying that it is connect and ready in the end, my application is down and any code below HGETALL operation is not done. IF i change hgetall to get\hget\anything , it will throw the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was the problem. If someone is new to redis as i am, redis commander and redis masternode are two different things. Commander is ui interface to work with Redis. And Masternode is database itself. I was connecting to commander instead of database)